# Custom Routes in NuxtJS

Tags: nuxt.js

I am wondering how to rename routes in nuxtjs.

In particular, I have a folder called `pages` with a number of files in that folder (like `about-us`, `contact-us`, etc).  However, I do NOT want the route to be `www.mysite.com/pages/about-us`, but rather `www.mysite.com/about-us`.  That is to say, I want to remove `pages` from the route.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what version of nuxt you're using or how you created your project but out of the box nuxt does exactly what you want. All the 'page' files are stored in the 'pages' folder but the route doesn't display '.../pages/...' in the url. See [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/)

Comment: Do you have a ***page*** folder inside nuxt default ***page*** folder?

Answer (score 8):

To customize the route path, simply, you can use [extendRoutes](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#extendroutes) function in the `nuxt.config.js` and edit the path property like this:

```
export default {
  ...
  router: {
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      return [
        {
          name: 'about',
          path: '/my-about-us', // <--- change this
          component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/about/index.vue'),
          chunkName: 'pages/about/index'
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure to return all of the routes (not only about page). I used `console.log(routes)` to know that.

Or, you can use a condition like this:

```
extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
  for (const route of routes) {
    if (route.path.includes('/about')) {
      route.path = '/my-about-us'
    }
  }
  return routes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Routing in nuxt.js documentation page](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/), it will automatically generate routes **without** pages/.

Is it possible that you have pages child folder inside the src/client/pages folder?

Answer (score 1):

You should add something like this...

```
routes: [
  {
    path: '/about-us',
    name: 'about_us',
    component: AboutUs
  }
]
```

so you could choose the path and the component

Answer (score 1):

Well with nuxtjs, you shouldn't need to do much for routing.
If it's just that you need your urls to be

1. www.mysite.com/about-us
2. www.mysite.com/contact-us

All you need to do is, have those two .vue files direct child to pages folder
Like the image below, this should do it.

[image]

Although I understand your question, if there's any custom functionality to manipulate routing, I'm not sure if there is anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [extendRoutes](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#extendroutes) function to the `nuxt.config.js` file inside the router property

```
export default {
  router: {
    extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
      // get your routes Array and do what ever you like
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If You Are In

> pages Directory

Your route will be the files inside the page directory.

**
Or You Can add custom routes. Instructions are listed below.......

> 1 . Add @nuxtjs/router dependency to your project {yarn add --dev > >@nuxtjs/router # or npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/router}.

> 2. add @nuxtjs/router to the buildModules section of nuxt.config.js.

That should work for your custom routes.js.
Then you make your own routes and map any directory you want.

> For More to Know. Visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/router

............ Thank you ..........................

Comment: please follow[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have different paths for different languages you can use nuxtI18n to achieve this directly in the `.vue` file, for example

```
export default {
  nuxtI18n: {
    paths: {
      en: '/about-us', // -> accessible at /about-us (no prefix since it's the default locale)
      fr: '/a-propos', // -> accessible at /fr/a-propos
      es: '/sobre'     // -> accessible at /es/sobre
    }
  }
}
```

For more info, [see documentaion](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/custom-paths/)

Answer (score -1):

You can go to other route with this as easily.

```html
<nuxt-link   to="/your_custom_url" >
      <button @click="your_function">Go Next URL</button>
</nuxt-link>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a button inside a nuxt-link triggering a function. Just add the `@click` event to it.